# Java adding and accessing resource on the build path

Tags: java, classpath

I am setting up a project that requires several non java resource that will ship with the application, I have created a directory structure in my project root directory.

```
src/                           - Java packages and classes
resource/media/icons/          - Button, form and table icons
resource/media/images/         - Report and application images
resource/media/reports/        - Jasper report templates
resource/help/                 - Help documentation
```

I added the resource directory to the class path by adding it as a source folder, is this the correct way to do this?

When I export the project will the resource also export?

How should I should be accessing these files, what would the URL be to access the ShippintTimes report template in the resource/media/reports/ directory?

```
// Current example accessing a report
String reportUrl = "resource/media/reports/ShippintTimes.jasper"
```

Do I need to do anything to make the URL operation system independent?

Are there any conventions regarding where to place non java application resource?

I know there are several questions, any hints help or examples as to how I should be structuring my project reports will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think I may have got a little complicates in my question, what I real need is an example of accessing resource in a java project.

Comment: you can read this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-loader-with-getresource-example/

Comment: new File("resource/fileName"); //resource independent.

Comment: here is some example: http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/java/system/java-resource-loading-explained-absolute-and-relative-names-difference-between-classloader-and-class-resource-loading

Comment: MadProgrammer - i'm using Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

As long as your resource folder is in classpath you can refer to resources in your project by:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("path");
```

Note that the absolute path here starts without / and relative starts with /
See: [File loading by getClass().getResource()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14089228/10330374)